# Error while deploying maven build from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, artifactory

Migrating to new Jenkins and new Artifactory  , when I set up the jobs in the new Jenkins, the maven jobs fail when deploying using the Artifactory plugin.  I have couple of other project that are Angular based and they deploy fine using the spec, but maven projects build fine but won’t deploy.  Also, is there a way to enable tracing on the plugin.
Any advice would be appreciated
Jenkins  2.361.4
Artifactory  7.49.5
Plugin  3.18
Here is the code

```
artifactoryServer = Artifactory.newServer url: 'https://artifactory-gggggggggg.com/artifactory',   
     credentialsId:’yyyyyyyyy'

     buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
     rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
     buildInfo.name = env.JOB_NAME
     buildInfo.number = env.BUILD_NUMBER
     rtMaven.tool = 'Maven 3.5.4'
     rtMaven.resolver server: artifactoryServer
     rtMaven.deployer server: artifactoryServer, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local/' , snapshotRepo: 'libs-   
     snapshot-local/' 
    
     rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false

     buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: ' -U clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -   
     Dmaven.repo.local=.m2 -Drevision=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT'

     rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
     artifactoryServer.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

```
And here is the stack trace

java.io.IOException: JFrog service failed. Received 404: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.throwException(JFrogService.java:49)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.Upload.handleUnsuccessfulResponse(Upload.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.execute(JFrogService.java:121)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.Upload.execute(Upload.java:77)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.upload(ArtifactoryManager.java:267)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.upload(ArtifactoryManager.java:262)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$deploy$4(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:46)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing artifact to Artifactory: /data/jenkins/workspace/egration_MITe_AnotherGCPTest0124/target/???/????/RPMS/noarch/????SNAPSHOT-20230124_24_1.jar.
 Skipping deployment of remaining artifacts (if any) and build info.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$deploy$4(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:57)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deploy(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$null$1(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:34)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:36)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:38)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.deployers.Deployer$LateDeployCallable.invoke(Deployer.java:364)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.deployers.Deployer$LateDeployCallable.invoke(Deployer.java:335)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1175)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.deployers.Deployer.deployArtifacts(Deployer.java:224)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.DeployStep$Execution.runStep(DeployStep.java:42)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.DeployStep$Execution.runStep(DeployStep.java:30)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.run(ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:55)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am expecting the maven assets to deploy to the maven repo in Artifactory

Comment: That: `JFrog service failed. Received 404` means the authentications fails...

Comment: But I have other jobs that are not maven and able to connect and upload and download, even this maven job,  I can see that it does download from Antifactory, we are using the same process to connect to Artifactory in both                          artifactoryServer = Artifactory.newServer url: 'https://artifactory-gggggggggg.com/artifactory',   
     credentialsId:’yyyyyyyyy'

Comment: It's not relevant if other jobs work. This jobs works obviously not. The credentials given are not correct... furthermore I would say you are using an very old Maven version.. furthermore if the response is HTML code the url might also be wrong...